# I am trying to implement this algorithm to display the name of a person who has the highest salary

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

The method is returning the name but it's returning the name in the first position of the array: but I want it to return Part Time Employee with highest salary:

Here is what I tried, this is the method:

```
public string PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary()
    {
        string name = employees[0].GetName();
        double salary = employees[0].GetSalary();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (employees[i].GetSalary() > salary && employees[i] is PartTimeEmployee)
            {
                salary = employees[i].GetSalary();
                name = employees[i].GetName();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
```

and here is the program codes. The expected result is "Wills" but I'm getting "Muwana"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee EmpS1 = new ServiceEmployee("S123", "Muwana", "Sein",1000);
        Employee EmpS2 = new ServiceEmployee("S124", "Prince", "Jack",1500);
        Employee EmpS3 = new ServiceEmployee("S125", "Matengu", "Prince",6000);
        Employee EmpP1 = new PartTimeEmployee("P133", "Mad", "Max",2500);
        Employee EmpP2 = new PartTimeEmployee("P134", "Wills", "Sanjay",3000);
        Employee EmpP3 = new PartTimeEmployee("P135", "Rick", "Sanchez",1000);
        Employee EmpM1 = new ManagementEmployee("M143", "Morty", "Smith",1500);
        Employee EmpM2 = new ManagementEmployee("M143", "Summer", "Smith",6500);
        Employee EmpM3 = new ManagementEmployee("M144", "Beth", "Smith",6500);

        HRDepartment company = new HRDepartment(500);

        company.AddEmployee(EmpS1);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpS2);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpS3);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpP1);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpP2);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpP3);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpM1);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpM2);
        company.AddEmployee(EmpM3);

        //-1. PartTime employee with highest salary
        Console.WriteLine("PartTime employee with highest salary:{0}",company.PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary());
```

Comment: Where is `count` in the condition of your `for` loop coming from? Do you have an `int count = 0` somewhere that you are not showing?

Comment: Add  all `classes` You Used Like `HRDepartment ` ,`Employee` and ...

Comment: Off-topic, but this seems to be an exercise, so i will be a bit pedantic...
You are not returning the `PartTimeEmployee` with the highest salary, you are returing it's name - double check what the requirement is :)

Comment: How are `employees` and `count` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out in the comments the problem most likely is with the `count` variable that's used in your loop condition. It's value is either <0, 0, or 1. Hence the loop is never entered or it stops after the first iteration.

There are several ways to address this:

- Check the value of count and make sure it aligns with the length of `employees`.
- Do not implement such a search by yourself and use the standard library for that:

```cs
public string PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary() => employees
    .OfType<PartTimeEmployee>()
    .MaxBy(x => x.GetSalary())
    .GetName();
// or in case employees might not contain any part-timers:
public string? PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary() => employees
    .OfType<PartTimeEmployee>()
    .MaxBy(x => x.GetSalary())?
    .GetName();
```

- Use the `Count` property of the employees list (or `Length` if it's an array; or `Count()` if you're not sure) instead of the `count` variable/member:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++)
```

Another problem was pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74097303/1025555): your initialization of `name` and `salaray` are wrong. This could be fixed like so:

```cs
public string? PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary()
{
    string? name = null;
    double salary = double.MinValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count(); i++)
    {
        // same as before
    }
    
    return name;
}
```

Now `PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary()` will return `null` if there is no part-time employee in the company.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not that bad, but this is wrong:

```
string name = employees[0].GetName();
double salary = employees[0].GetSalary();
```

This would work only if you could guarantee that employees[0] is a part-time employee.

Instead, initialize salary with -1. That should work. Of course you should then also check for whether salary is still -1 after the execution of the loop, which means that the loop has not encountered any part-time employee.

Comment: While that is a valid point and it will prevent wrong results in some situations, it won't resolve the current issue, because it seems the loop's body isnt' executed at all. Otherwise, if the code was looking at all employees, it wouldn't return the employee with the lowest salary in the whole list ...

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your `PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary` with the below implementation

```
public string PartTimeEmployeeWithHighestSalary()
{
   return employees.OfType<PartTimeEmployee>().OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).First().Name;
}
```

Comment: No need to sort the whole list when you only need to find the maximum. Use [`MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-7.0) instead.

Comment: The `ToList()` is also not needed.

Comment: Your code will throw an exception if the list of employees doesn't contain any `PartTimeEmployee` (as will OP's code) ... Furthermore sorting and then taking the first, will turn an *O(n)*  operation (finding the maximum) into an *O(n\*log(n))*  operation for no reason ...

Comment: @KhawajaAsim I downvoted your question especially because I think, sorting the list is not the best approach for just finding the maximum. OP's approach is -- if implementend correctly, the problem is probably caused only by some wrong initial values -- totally fine, and furthermore faster than yours ...